# How to run feature file more than once at the same time

Tags: automation, cucumber

I'm using cucumber automation code.

This is my feature  file:

```
Feature: ayamobile Registration Level 3  

Scenario: scenario_01 register with valid data as a Client using level 3 methode
    Given I am on  Registeration Page level 3 from agent page
    When Registeration with valid data as a client
    Then client activation with pk2
```

How to run feature file more than once at the same time?

Comment: Are you looking to run the feature in parallel or multiple times one after the other?

Comment: i need run my feature file in parallel

Comment: how i can do it ?

Comment: https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/